# jpa delete error, while print the update sql

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I use JPA `delete`, I get an error. I check the log and find an update SQL, I don't know why I execute the deleting, but it prints update SQL

java 1.8, spring-data-jpa-2.1.8

the source code:

```java
cardApplyRepository.delete(CardApply.builder().activityId(23443L).build());
```

the log:

```sh
2019-07-15 13:09:20.478 [main] INFO  o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet [initServletBean:546]     - Completed initialization in 19 ms
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        t_card_apply
        (activity_id, activity_name, app_id, card_base_required_id, card_id, mass_msg_id, seller_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-07-15 13:09:20.573 [main] WARN  o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper [logExceptions:137]     - SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2019-07-15 13:09:20.574 [main] ERROR o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper [logExceptions:142]     - Column 'card_base_required_id' cannot be null

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:296)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy206.delete(Unknown Source)
    at com.geek.icem.wechat.service.impl.WxCardServiceImplTest.deleteCard(WxCardServiceImplTest.java:34)
```

Comment: Seems like it is inserting a row to the _t_card_apply_ table with null value for _card_base_required_id_ .

Comment: try using ".deleteInBatch()" option. first, u need to fetch the entity from the table or delete by using the primary key

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an Entity to the `delete` method it should be managed at this point.

For example by using the `findById` method and passing the result to `delete`.

You are passing a non-managed entity as you build it on the fly.

So either fetch one first or use the `deleteById` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

We might not inspect your issue in detail unless you provide the code of `CardApply` and `CardApplyRepository` if you are using a custom repository implementation.

What I can get is, you want to delete an entity by id, so, I suggest you that just use the `deleteById` method of Spring data's `CrudRepository` like below:

```java
cardApplyRepository.deleteById(23443L);
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!